# Dropdown error in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I am using rails 5 and ruby 2.2.2

### Models::

```
class Office < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :office
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

### Views:: (_form.html.erb in photos)

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :office %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:office_id, Office.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :employee %>
  <%= collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>     

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :photo %>
  <%= collection_select(:photo_id, Photo.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>     

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

But I am getting this error:

> undefined method `office_id' for #< Photo:0x007f9953363730>

I think office is not connected to photo directly, that's why getting this error. I tried with "through" in model but still getting error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Try  <%= f.collection_select(:office_ids, Office.all, :id, :name) %> , collection_singular_ids  method

Comment: Can you please post the table structure for Photo model

Comment: It's not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the helper on form object (`Photo`)

```
<%= f.collection_select(:office_id, Office.all, :id, :name) %>
```

So make sure you have `office_id` attribute in `Photo` model

also, you are not using `f` for these two `collection_selects`

```
<%= collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= collection_select(:photo_id, Photo.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: I am using f for two collection_select. It was just a typo. Office can not be in photo model. Because Photo belongs to Office through Employee. They are not directly connected.